# Re: Getting a cross join of all the dimension attributes in a list report

Tags: cognos

This is the scenario,

I have a case which has the following dimensions, Case Identifier,Case Owner, Case Status, Case Creation Date, Case Resolution Date. I am trying to create a list which displays all the dimension attributes like

Case Identifier | Case Status | Case Owner | Case Creation Date | Case Resolution Date

I have my fact table which links all these dimension keys..

My goal is to show all these attributes for each and every case, but when i am trying to add all these to a list in a report, i am getting a Cartesian join of all the dimension attributes.

Please suggest what could be the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, it sure sounds like one or more of your dimensions aren't joined to your fact table.  Add them one at a time, see which one(s) fail.

Comment: I'll add that you want to make sure you have the right cardinality between the dimensions and the fact tables. In general, you should have a many-to-1 relationship between the fact table and all dimensions. Having the cardinality reversed won't cause a cross join but it could result in a many-to-many join which is almost as bad.